# pythonでtxtファイル内にあるヒストグラムのデータを量的データにばらして配列に格納したい

Tags: python, python3

Jupyter Notebookを使いPython3でプログラムを作成しようとしています。

行いたいことは、txtファイル内にあるヒストグラムのデータを"元の量的データにばらして"配列へ読み込むことです。
txtファイル内には複数のヒストグラムに関する情報が記述してあります。
1列目にはヒストグラムの名前が書いてあります。(例：Band1, Band2, Band3,・・・)
2列目にはヒストグラムの階級値(DN)があり、
3列目には2列目の階級値に対応する度数(Npts)が記述してあります。
各ヒストグラムの情報は、1行改行して書き分けてあります。
また、txtファイルは複数のスペース区切りで記述されています。
txtファイルの内容は以下のようになっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このtxtファイルから以下のような配列を生成したいです。

```
Band1[178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181,・・・]
Band2[179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 180, 181, 181,・・・]
Band3[181, 181, ・・・]
```

以下追記

回答ありがとうございます！txtファイルの読み込み方が分かりました。
そして、分かりにくい質問で申し訳ありません。
私が生成したい配列は以下のようなものではなく

```
Band1 [178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, ・・・]
```

以下のような配列を作成したいです。

```
Band1[178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181,・・・]
```

恐らく、DN値とNpts値についてfor文を回し、Npts値の数だけ配列に同じDN値を格納していく、、、というようなプログラムになるかと考えています。 例えばDN値が198でNpts値が4の時には、配列に198という値を4個入れるようにする

Comment: 問題のどの部分は分かってて, どの部分がわからないなど, もう少し詳細書いたほうがよいでしょう。まるきり全部だと丸投げなので, 自分の書いたコードを(途中まででも良いので)載せたほうがよいでしょう(回答付けたあとだけど)

Comment: 回答とご指摘ありがとうございます。
今後質問する際には、途中でもコードを載せるようにします。
1日かけてもこの問題を自分で解決することが出来なかったので、とても助かりました。お時間を割いて回答して頂いた皆様に大変感謝いたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[「複数のHistogramデータを量的データに戻して二次元配列に格納したい」のコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/93676#comment107044_93676)から引用:

> txtファイルは複数のスペース区切りになっております。

Pandas の `pandas.read_fwf()` を使います。

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', header=None, names=['Band', 'DN', 'Npts'])
band = df.query('Band != "Histogram"').ffill().astype({'DN': int, 'Npts': int})\
         .groupby('Band').apply(lambda x: x['DN'].repeat(x['Npts']).to_list()).to_dict()

print(band)

# {'Band 1': [178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, ...,
#  'Band 2': [179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 180, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, ...,
#  'Band 3': [181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, 182, ...,]}
```

ちなみに、Band ごとにデータフレームを分割する場合は以下の様にします。

```py
df = df.query('Band != "Histogram"').ffill().astype({'DN': int, 'Npts': int})
dfx = [g.reset_index(drop=True) for _, g in df.groupby('Band')]

print(dfx[0])
print(dfx[1])
print(dfx[2])

#      Band   DN  Npts
# 0  Band 1  178     1
# 1  Band 1  179     2
# 2  Band 1  180     3
# 3  Band 1  181     6
# 4  Band 1  182     8
# 5  Band 1  183    10
# 6  Band 1  184    10
#
#      Band   DN  Npts
# 0  Band 2  179     6
# 1  Band 2  180     1
# 2  Band 2  181     5
# 3  Band 2  182    13
# 4  Band 2  183    21
#
#      Band   DN  Npts
# 0  Band 3  181     6
# 1  Band 3  182     8
# 2  Band 3  183    10
# 3  Band 3  184    10
# 4  Band 3  185    11
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
作りたい配列を作成することが出来ました。
色々、私の説明に不備があり大変ご迷惑おかけしました。

Answer (score 0):

以下のスクリプトファイルと同じフォルダにsample.txtが存在することを前提にしています。

コードの解説はしませんので、調べてみてください。

```py
import pathlib

txt_path = str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent) + '\\sample.txt'

data_dict = dict()

with open(txt_path, "r") as f:
    datas = f.readlines()
    usage = None
    for data in datas:
        if data:
            data_head = data.split()
            if data_head:
                if 'Histogram' in data_head:
                    pass
                elif len(data_head) == 4:
                    usage = ''.join(data_head[:2])
                    DN, npts = list(map(int, data_head[2:]))
                    data_dict[usage] = {
                        'DN': [DN, ],
                        'Npts': [npts, ],
                    }
                elif len(data_head) == 2:
                    DN, npts = list(map(int, data_head))
                    data_dict[usage]['DN'].append(DN)
                    data_dict[usage]['Npts'].append(npts)

print(data_dict)
```

結果出力

```
{'Band1': {'DN': [178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183], 'Npts': [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10]}, 'Band2': {'DN': [179, 180, 181], 'Npts': [6, 1, 5]}, 'Band3': {'DN': [181, 182, 183], 'Npts': [6, 8, 10]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python標準パッケージから groupby使う方法

1. まず無駄な行を取り除き
2. Histogram が記載されていない行を補完し
3. 最後に groupbyでまとめる

(**少し更新**)

```py
with open(textfile) as fp:
    lst = [ln.split() for ln in fp
                if not ln.startswith('Histogram') and ln.strip()]

res = []
for ln in lst:
    n = len(ln)
    if n > 2:
        pre = ''.join(ln[:n -2])
    res.append([pre] +ln[-2:])

from itertools import groupby, repeat
for k,g in groupby(res, key=lambda ln: ln[0]):
    print(k, sum((list(repeat(int(ln[1]), int(ln[2])))for ln in g), start=[]))

# Band1 [178, 179, 179, 180, 180, 180, 181, 181, 181, 181,
# Band2 [179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 179, 180, 181, 181, 181,
# Band3 [181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 182, 182, 182, 182,
```