# 複数のHistogramデータを量的データに戻して二次元配列に格納したい

Tags: python

Jupyter Notebookを使いPython3でプログラムを作成しようとしています。

ヒストグラムのデータ(階級値と度数)が記述されているtxtファイルから、データを読み込みそれぞれのヒストグラムのデータを量的データにばらしてから、各ヒストグラムの量的データごとにまとめて二次元配列に格納したいです。(分かりずらい表現ですみません)
以下はヒストグラムのデータが入ったtxtファイルの内容です。Band1とBand2という2つのヒストグラムのデータがあります。DN列は階級値で、Npts列は度数の列です。

```
Histogram       DN     Npts
Band 1           1        1
                 2        2
                 3        1

Histogram       DN     Npts
Band 2           2        1
                 3        2
                 4        1
```

以下では、ヒストグラムの量的データを別々に表示するところまでのプログラムです。

```
with open(path) as fp:
    # 無駄な行を取り除く
    lst = [ln.split() for ln in fp
                if not ln.startswith('Histogram') and ln.strip()]

res = []
#Histgramが記載されていない行を補完する
for ln in lst:
    n = len(ln)

    if n > 2:
        pre = ''.join(ln[:n -2])
    res.append([pre] +ln[-2:])

#groupbyでまとめる
from itertools import groupby, repeat
for k,g in groupby(res, key=lambda ln: ln[0]):
    sublist = []
    print(k, sum((list(repeat(int(ln[1]), int(ln[2])))for ln in g), start=[]))
#Band1 [1, 2, 2, 3]
#Band2 [2, 3, 3, 4]
```

出力させたい2次元配列を以下に示します

```
[[1, 2, 2, 3], [2, 3, 3, 4]]
```

イテレーターがよくわからず、上手く配列に格納できません。
-追記-
Bandごとにファイルを分けたり、Excelに入れてシート別に入れたいのですが、データを入手する際に30個ほどのBandがまとめて出力されてしまいます。そのため、各Bandについてファイルを作成することが困難です。こう言った理由で、1つのファイルに複数のバンドがまとめて入ったものを読み込んで配列に格納したいと考えています。
(元データはソフトウェアENVIの統計情報です)

Comment: 前回の質問もそうですが、サンプルのデータもスクリーンショットではなくテキストで提示するようにしてください。こちらの記事を参考に。[スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765/26370)

Comment: それから同様に前回の質問もそうですが、何故1つのファイルに全てのデータを入れているのでしょう？ テキストファイルならそれぞれの塊(Band毎)を別々のファイルにするとか、1つにまとめたいならExcelのファイルにして塊(Band毎)をそれぞれシートにするなどすれば、あとはファイル名やシート名(インデックス？)を変えて繰り返すことで、それぞれは単純な処理に出来ると思います。そういう元々のデータの内容や構成を、他でも使い回しやすいように考慮しておけば、少し処理を変える度にデータを読み込んだり加工したりする方法を新規に考える手間が少なくなるでしょう。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
ファイルに関してですが、元データがアップしたtxtファイルのように複数Bandがまとめて入っているもので、かつ、Band数(ヒストグラムの数)が30以上あります。そのため、各Bandに対応したファイルを作成することが困難であるので、元データのtxtファイルをそのまま読み込もうとしております。
ただ、確かにKunifさんのご指摘の通り、Bandごとにファイルが分かれていたら、簡単であると思います。txtファイル内にある複数のBand情報に対応するファイルを作成するプログラムについて検討しようと思います。

Comment: データファイルですが、前回の質問では「タブ区切り」だと説明されていました。ですが、今回のデータにはタブが含まれておらず、列の区切りは複数のスペースになっています。実際のデータはどうなっているのでしょう？

Comment: 私の勘違いでした、確かにtxtファイルは複数のスペース区切りになっております。

Comment: @mik ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

もしかしたらこの質問は [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701) であって、追記された「Bandごとにファイルを分けたり、Excelに入れてシート別に入れたい」というのも私がコメントした内容を取り入れたからなのでは？

質問内容は中間的な段階の処理であって、実は以下のような形の2次元配列を作りたいのではありませんか？ 集計(されたように見える)結果を階級値の並びに展開し直すといった処理は、当初の計測/発生した時刻とか場所の別のデータと紐付けられているといったことで無ければ意味が無いように思えます。

■各Bandデータを列として横に並べる

```
   Band 1 Band 2
DN
1       1
2       2      1
3       1      2
4              1
```

■各Bandデータを行として縦に並べる

```
DN      1  2  3  4
Band 1  1  2  1
Band 2     1  2  1
```

以前の質問のデータも同様に以下の形にしたいのでは？

```
    Band 1 Band 2 Band 3
DN
178      1
179      2      6
180      3      1
181      6      5      6
182      8     13      8
183     10     21     10
184     10     31     10
185     11     12     11
186     15      5     10
187     17            17
188     13            13
189     10            10
190      1             1
```

あるいはこちら

```
DN     178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190
Band 1   1   2   3   6   8  10  10  11  15  17  13  10   1
Band 2       6   1   5  13  21  31  12   5
Band 3               6   8  10  10  11  10  17  13  10   1
```

上記はこんなプログラムで出来ます。

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import io

sep = re.compile(r'\n[\s]*\n')

#### 1つのファイルにまとめられたデータをそれぞれのバンド毎に切り離す
#### 各バンドデータは空白行で区切られているものとする
datafile = 'sample.txt'
with open(datafile) as f:
    bandarray = sep.split(f.read())

#### 各バンドデータをpandas DataFrameとして読み込み、結合する
#### 縦軸(行)が階級値、横軸(列)が対応するバンド
result = pd.DataFrame()
for band in bandarray:
    df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(band), dtype='str')
    bandname = df['Histogram'][0]
    df = df[['DN','Npts']]
    df.columns = ['DN',bandname]
    df.set_index('DN', inplace=True)
    result = pd.concat([result, df], axis=1)

#### 各バンドで存在しない階級値が NaN になっているので空文字列に変換する
result.fillna('', inplace=True)

#### 配列にまとめた結果を表示する
print('====Bandデータを列として横に並べる====')
print(result)
print('')
print('====Bandデータを行として縦に並べる====')
print(result.T)
```

結果をそのままCSVやExcelの形式でファイルに書き出せば、バンド毎のファイルやシートに分けるよりも、その後のデータ加工が簡単になると思われます。

Answer (score 0):

既に個々のリストが出力できているなら，それらを一つのリストに格納すれば御希望の出力は得られそうです。具体的には最後の `for k, g in ...` 以降を下記のように変更します。

```
all_list = []
for k, g in groupby(res, key=lambda ln: ln[0]):
    sublist = sum((list(repeat(int(ln[1]), int(ln[2])))
                   for ln in g), start=[])
    print(k, sublist)
    all_list.append(sublist)

print(all_list)
```